# Sending Notification emails from Jenkins?

Tags: java, email, jenkins, server

I am trying to setup a jenkins for build automation in our company. I was tring to send email notication from jenkins when a build finishes. I installed the email-ext and tried configuring it. I provided the SMTP server and port alone and tried test email. Then I am getting the following error. I am new to this all, Please help.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)

    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)

    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)

    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:527)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor248.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)

    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:86)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)

    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)

    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)

    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:576)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect

    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)

    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)

    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)

    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)

    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:286)

    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)

    ... 76 more
```

I am also getting the following error `"It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken."` I googled for it but I didn't understand anything...please help me on this also.
The Jenkins version I am using is 1.588

Comment: Can you please put some of your configuration settings here. Especially how you configured mailing.

Comment: Do you have other tools that use this SMTP that succeed sending email through it? Are you sure port 25 is the right one?

Answer (score 0):

Please check following :

- Try to verify whether the host name/ip of the SMTP mail server is
  correct or not.
- make sure there is no host entry for the provided ip or hostname in /etc/hosts file.
- Telnet the SMTP mail server see whether if the connection can be
  establish or not. Generally in corporates they white list other then
  default port ( 25 ). Check with your IT team and confirm the ip and
  port again.
- There can be other cause if IPv6 is getting used, Please try
  connecting by adding following jvm argument and try connecting with
  IPv4 argument as below :

  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true